# Constructing an instance of EnumeratedDistribution in Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-commons-math

I am having a terrible time doing some trivial: creating a new instance of [org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.EnumeratedDistribution](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/EnumeratedDistribution.html) in Scala. Best I can make out the following should work...

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.EnumeratedDistribution
import org.apache.commons.math3.util.Pair

val p = new Pair(1L, 0.5)
val q = new Pair(2L, 0.5)
val mapping = new java.util.ArrayList[Pair[Long, Double]]()
mapping.add(p)
mapping.add(q)

val dist = new EnumeratedDistribution(mapping)
```

...this fails with the following error in the REPL...

```
scala>     val dist = new EnumeratedDistribution[Long](mapping)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.ArrayList[org.apache.commons.math3.util.Pair[Long,scala.Double]]
 required: java.util.List[org.apache.commons.math3.util.Pair[Long,java.lang.Double]]
       val dist = new EnumeratedDistribution[Long](mapping)
```

I was under the impression that `java.util.List` is abstract and thus one must use something like `ArrayList` instead.  I am sure this is something trivial.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from the `Double` type: `java.lang.Double` is expected while you use `scala.Double`.

Simply try:

```
val mapping = new java.util.ArrayList[Pair[Long, java.lang.Double]]()
```

Then it should work since as you said yourself, `ArrayList` implements `List`.